# Run-Jetty-Run (RJR) with Jetty 8 and Servlet 3.0 scanns all JAR files ignoring WebInfIncludeJarPattern in jetty-web.xml

Tags: eclipse, jetty, servlet-3.0, runjettyrun

I'm using Servlet 3.0 without any web.xml just using Spring WebApplicationInitializer. When I start the Webapplication with Run-Jetty-Run in eclipse, the JARScanning takes about 40 seconds since it tries to find HandlesTypes annotations in all jars.

Thus, I tried to set the WebInfIncludeJarPattern in the jetty-web.xml (I also tried jetty-context.xml) and put it in the webapp/WEB-INF folder as described in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment. I also set metadata-complete="true". The content of the jetty-web.xml file is:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
      <Arg>.*/.*foo-api-[^/]\.jar$|./.*bar-[^/]\.jar$|./.*wibble[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

However, the JarScanner still scans all the JAR files. In the debug output I can see, that the jetty-web.xml file is parsed AFTER all the JARScanning is done:

OUTPUT:

```
2013-08-30 09:09:52.836:DBUG:oejw.WebAppContext:preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/admin2,[file:/C:/....../src/main/webapp/]} with runjettyrun.webapp.RJRWebInfConfiguration@1cdc4a5
......
2013-08-30 09:09:52.979:DBUG:oejw.WebAppContext:preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/admin2,[file:/C:/..../src/main/webapp/]} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration@136f39e
2013-08-30 09:09:53.076:DBUG:oejw.WebDescriptor:file:/C:/......../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml: Calculated metadatacomplete = True with version=3.0
2013-08-30 09:09:53.076:DBUG:oejw.WebAppContext:preConfigure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/admin2,[file:/C:/....../src/main/webapp/]} with runjettyrun.webapp.RJRMetaInfoConfiguration@164de63
... <LOTS OF JARSCANNING>
2013-08-30 09:10:36.677:DBUG:oejw.JarScanner:Search of file:/C:/......./httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
2013-08-30 09:10:36.710:DBUG:oejw.WebAppContext:configure o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/.................} with org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration@803365
2013-08-30 09:10:36.711:DBUG:oejw.JettyWebXmlConfiguration:Configuring web-jetty.xml
2013-08-30 09:10:36.715:DBUG:oejw.JettyWebXmlConfiguration:Configure: file:/C:/......./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml
```

How can I force RJR to pick up the jetty-web.xml earlier and only scan the files specified in there? Or is there any other way in RJR to specify the JARS to be scanned?

I am using following versions: Eclipse: Kepler Release 4.3 Build id: 20130614-0229 RJR:  1.3.3.201301020723  Jetty: 8.1.8.v20121106

WINDOWS: 64 bit

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a workaround for speeding up Jetty 8 with Servlet 3.x.

1. Create a file (jetty.xml)
2. Open the RJR configuration
3. Click on "Show advanced options"
4. Additional Jetty.xml:

The file (jetty.xml) must have these lines:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Get name="handler">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
      <Arg>.*/mwa-web-.*\.jar$</Arg>
    </Call>
  </Get>
</Configure>
```

Here, I'm telling Jetty that any file starting with mwa-web-* should be scanned for Servlet 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the RJR source code I came across this undocumented flag *rjrDisableannotation* which speeds up the startup time significantly in all Jetty 8/9/9.3.6 (so far I haven't noticed any unwanted side effects - of course as its name suggests it doesn't scan for annotations anymore).

It can be enabled as a "VM argument" in the "Run/Debug configuration" for a "Jetty Webapp".

e.g.:

```
-DrjrDisableannotation=true
```

Here the related source code for reference:

https://github.com/xzer/run-jetty-run/blob/rjr1.3.4/Jetty8Support/plugin-jetty8/bootstrap/runjettyrun/Configs.java#L210-L212

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16630269)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I provided a more stable link to a tagged version to reduce the chance to become invalid